# working with dropdown in sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

Currently working with dropdown column in the moss 2007.

my question is

I created dropdown column in a list, it has 3 options. Suppose if option1 is selected then the new field (let say a text box) should pop up, if option2 is selected the another new field (say a dropdown should pop up) and similarly for option3. How to make these things show up when certain option in drop down selected? should I need to code for it? Educate me!  Article would be a great help.

P.S->> Our organisation isn't so keen in working with infopath, infopath is out of option. Can I code in sharepoint designer itself???

Comment: Thanks for the reply appreciate your time. I have to confine myself to the OOTB features since our organisation is against the custom development. Through my research I found out jquery would be very helpful in these cases, but i am still wondering when it can able to enable or disable(or hide or make visible) the columns with respect to the option selected in drop downs. Letsay option 1 selected in drpdwn, then text box should be visible,if option 2 selected letsay date picker should be disabled. Any article regarding this would be a great help. Newbie to the sharepoint so pardon my Knowledge

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible using only SharePoint out-of-the-box (OOTB). It would require building a custom solution. You would need to create a custom field for each option, that checks the value of the choice field and determines whether to hide itself based on that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply appreciate your time. I have to confine myself to the OOTB features since our organisation is against the custom development. Through my research I found out jquery would be very helpful in these cases, but i am still wondering when it can able to enable or disable(or hide or make visible) the columns with respect to the option selected in drop downs. Letsay option 1 selected in drpdwn, then text box should be visible,if option 2 selected letsay date picker should be disabled. Any article regarding this would be a great help. Newbie to the sharepoint so pardon my Knowledge